# Eclipse Luna Java8 Beta

Tags: eclipse, java-8

I downloaded the latest java8 from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html which I believe is the official Java8 release.But my eclipse Luna still displays in its preferences that it is a Beta version
This is what I get after I type java -version

```
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

Is the build version a beta or is it the official one

Comment: Did you download the latest Eclipse Luna build? Downloading JDK 8 will not change the compiler used in eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upcoming Luna M7 milestone will have Java 8 support. Prior Luna builds don't have it. You can also add Java 8 support to Kepler SR2.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler

Once installed, you’ll need to tell your projects to use Java 8. First add the JDK to eclipse:

- Go to Window -> Preferences
- Go to Java -> Installed JREs
- Add Standard VM, and point to the location of the JRE
- Then go to Compiler
- Set Compiler compliance level to 1.8

Then tell the project to use JDK 1.8:

- Go to Project -> preferences
- Go to Java Compiler
- Enable project specific settings
- Set Compiler compliance level to 1.8

Comment: I don't know why this was up-voted, but this is certainly not sufficient to use Java 8 on Kepler. For one, you will not be able to set compiler compliance level to 1.8 until you install Java 8 patches for Kepler. http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/java8/

Comment: @Konstantin Komissarchik "until you install Java 8 patches for Kepler. eclipse.org/downloads/java8 " Isn't it the same thing that is explained in the guide he linked ?

Comment: The trouble with hidden links... I didn't realize that "this" was a link, so I read the answer as stating that the inline description was the guide. I will remove my down-vote and fix the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `b132` and `b70` values are build numbers and are the correct values for the release.